# Delete everything from second array that exists in first array Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got two arrays in my Jquery

```
     var results = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
     var chosen = ["1","A","3","B","5","C"];
```

How can i delete everything from results that exists in chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
var results = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"];
var chosen = ["1","A","3","B","5","C"];

var cnt = chosen.length;
while(--cnt, cnt >= 0) {
 if(results.indexOf(chosen[cnt]) > -1){
   chosen.splice(cnt,1)
 }
}
```

> Delete everything from second array that exists in first array Jquery

so `console.log(chosen); // "A","B","C"` will be the result.

Comment: @MuradEmi Glad to help! :) Try to press tick mark present inside anyone of the answers here, that helped you solving your issue. But this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < chosen.length; i++){
     if(results.indexOf(chosen[i]) > -1){
          results.splice(results.indexOf(chosen[i]),1);
      }
}
console.log(results);
```

results = > 2,4,6

Answer (score 0):

do a foreach on results and check if the value is contained into the chosen array, if it is, remove the value

Comment: Actually i did it like this 
             $.each( results, function( key, value ) {
                 if(jQuery.inArray(value, chosen) !== -1){
                    jQuery.grep(results, function(values) {
                        return value !=values ;
                    });
                 }
            });

Comment: Why would you use functions for a thing that you can do with a for? And of top of that, they're not even native javascript functions. I think both answers are better than using jquery each and grep, and faster.